# Catching mouseover on whitespaces in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover

How to catch mouseover event on whitespaces (blanks between text words) in a div? The div can contain html also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to wrap the whitespaces in elements, for example:

```
<div>content here and whitespaces</div>
<!-- wraping... -->
<div>content<div class="whitespace"> </div>here<div class="whitespace"> </div>and<div class="whitespace"> </div>whitespaces</div>
```

Then you can use [jQuery's live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to bind an event.

```
$(".whitespace").live("mouseover", function(e){
    // This should do...
});
```